# PyCharm - can only create a pure python project

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to create a Django project on PyCharm, but I can only see a Pure Python setting. Aren't there supposed to be others?

I searched stack overflow as well and jet brains, but I'm not sure why it's missing.

Thanks ppl ^_^

EDIT: My PyCharm version is 2016.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django is only present for professional, not the community edition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your PyCharm version is old.

In pycharm 2016.2.3, when creating project, you can see
[Django project setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9u9e.png)

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm 5.0.5 if you create a new project (File -> New Project), you can see the following window:

[image]

if you can't see this, try to upgrade your PyCharm, may be you have an old version as Mackong suggests.

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-django-project.html), you can find PyCharm documentation about this.

Comment: That's the thing, I have pycharm version 2016.2.3.
I already saw the documentation :S